# A word similar to "shame" that has a positive connotation

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word to express the feeling that you have when you don't want to weigh on someone but still have to ask for a favor out of need.

For example, consider the following sentence.

> He felt ashamed asking for a favor.

"Ashamed" has a negative connotation. Looking for a word that implies virtue (modesty, humility, down-to-earthness)

Comment: Please describe positive shame a little bit more. I think you're looking for a different idea.

Comment: You could say "He respectfully asked for a favour". (Which I'm not posting as an answer because it's not a synonym for or otherwise really comparable to shame.)

Comment: @Valkor Thank you! Revised the question to be more clear.

Comment: You mention humility in your question. I assume you considered 'humble' did you dismiss it for any particular reason?

Comment: He felt ... almost ashamed, asking for a favour.

Comment: Personally I would say that English does not have the concept of a positive shame. You might be wary of asking a favour due to feeling that it is asking too much, but that is also not particularly positive.

Answer (score 1):

The closest words that I found are "considerate" and "thoughtful"

For example, consider the following sentences.

> He was very considerate about asking for a favor because he was already indebted to her.

> He was very thoughtful about asking for a favor because he was already indebted to her.

These words are not exactly what I was looking for because of the following reasons.

- Both of these words are an action and not a feeling.
- "Considerate" is mostly used for the person who is on a higher ground.

However, these words somewhat serve the purpose.

**Interesting Fact:**

There is a word for this in Urdu language called "Haya"

- "Haya", noun translates to "Modesty"
- "Haya Aana", verb translates to the positive shame that I was talking about. The person is already indebted and feels shame in inconveniencing the other person by asking for another favor.

Comment: I wouldn't consider either of those words as being the positive equivalent of shame.

Answer (score 0):

Shame is negative, so a word with a positive connotation would be a very different word.

You mention modesty in your question, but that isn't in the sentence you wrote.
Discretion, or being discreet, is sometimes a positive reason to hide something.

Answer (score 0):

A positive word for shame about asking for a favor

*diffident*  adjective

> diffident adjective

dif·​fi·​dent | \ ˈdi-fə-dənt  , -ˌdent \

Definition of diffident

1 : hesitant in acting or speaking through lack of self-confidence

2 : RESERVED, UNASSERTIVE

https://merriam-webster.com/definitions/diffident

Comment: The person asking is not hesitant because of self-confidence but because he doesn't want to cause trouble, worry or even discomfort.

Answer (score 0):

How about abashed? Not as assertive as ashamed and invokes the more complex feeling you describe.
" made to feel uncomfortable, disconcerted, or embarrassed by something that has happened or been done or said"
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abashed

Comment: You should include a full definition of your chosen word with a dictionary link.

Comment: OK~sorry-new to this

Answer (score -1):

Thesaurus work gives many possibilities but none seems to fit the subtle change of meaning that you seek. The nearest I can get from other related concepts is “presumptuous”, which admits your negative embarrassment in asking, but keeps the balance of positive respect between you and the other person.

Comment: I have never heard of presumptuous being at all positive. Presumptuous is the opposite, really. The person asking has no embarrassment, nor any respect for a social construct being violated.

Comment: Yes, it is a difficult question. Do you have any other suggested answer?